# Probability Question about a multiple choice test

Tags: probability

If a person takes a $5$ question multiple choice test with four options, $a,b,c,d$ for each question, what is the probability that they will miss at least one question? Assume the person guesses on every question.

Here is what I have so far...

$P$(missing at least one question)= $1-P$(getting all of them right)

$1-3/4= 1/4$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The idea is correct, but the probability of getting all of them right is $(1/4)^5$, which gives a probability of $1-4^{-5} = \frac{1023}{1024}$.

Answer (score 2):

$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1 - 0.25^5$

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the person gets every guess right is ${(\frac 14)}^5$. Therefore, the probability that the person gets at least one question wrong is $1-{(\frac 14)}^5 = 
0.9990234375$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting all $5$ right is not 3/4. It's $1/4 \times 1/4 \times 1/4 \times 1/4 \times 1/4$. There are 5 questions, each of which you have a 1/4 chance of guessing correctly.

So P (missing at least one question)= 1-P(getting all of them right) = $1 - (1/4) \times (1/4) \times (1/4) \times (1/4) \times (1/4)$.